# REST service not working after creating CORSFilter removing filter does not resolve issue

Tags: java, rest, dependencies

I might need some help resolving this error.

I've got a working REST service in my application. I tested this service with postman and it worked. Yesterday I added a Angular frontend fo my application and needed a CORS filter to be able to access tghe REST service in my Java backend. This worked fine after some tweaking.

Last night my laptop decided that it was a good idea to restart and when I fired up my app this morning REST wasn't working at all. The stacktrace told me this:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[rest.ApplicationPath]: Servlet.service() for servlet rest.ApplicationPath threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ObjectProvider<FilterProvider> with qualifiers @Default 
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.writeTo(FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The filter looks like this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

/**
 *
 * @author Marcel de Groof m.degroof@student.fontys.nl
 */

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{
    @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }
}
```

The ApplicationPath class that seems to throw the error looks like this:

```
package rest;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * Basispath van de applicatie
 * @author Marcel
 */

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationPath extends Application{

}
```

The error states it's missing dependencies for type ObjectProvider with qualifiers @Default. I really hope someone can tell me which way to go to solve this, as I'm not sure which direction start looking. Please let me know if I need to provide more (detailed) information.

Answer (score 0):

As of today the problem seems to be (magically) fixed. The concerning part of the story is that I have no real view of what actually was wrong other than a (for me) unexplainable conflict between the Jersey (used in the project) and RESTEasy api (not used in the project).

The action that fixed the problem was: loading a backup version of the project and put the CORS filer back in place in this project. After that REST worked again and the dependency problem seemed to be fixed.

I still really wonder why the project wanted the RESTEasy dependency.